# How in iOS to get first date of the month?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I try to get first date for the current month from `[NSDate new]`. My problem is that instead of **2015/06/01** I always receive **2015/05/31**. I even try to convert string **20150601** to `NSDate` and I still receive **2015/05/31**.

Here is my CODE (for the second element):

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    currentMonth = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"20150601"];
```

The result is:

```
(lldb) print currentMonth
(__NSDate *) $0 = 0x79e64820 2015-05-31 21:00:00 UTC
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, I understand my mistake - I don't check correctly result of my operations. They always result in `UTC`.
10x, for answer and all comments. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: What you see is the time in `UTC` time zone.

Comment: You are getting the date correctly, you are just not checking it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
components.day = 1;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[formatter setTimeZone:zone];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];


NSDate *dayOneInCurrentMonth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSString *currentMonth = [formatter stringFromDate:dayOneInCurrentMonth];
NSLog(@"%@",currentMonth);
```

Output

```
2015-06-08 14:07:30.924 NSDATEDemo[1943:39838] 20150601
```

Comment: OK, you create an `NSDateComponents` instance and then you don't actually use it.  Why is that?

Comment: Agree with @Droppy, why do you have: `self.currentDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];`. Second it gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. The code is copy / paste from yours.

Comment: I Update my answer please check @new2ios

Comment: No, `2015-06-08 11:44:46.358 SpazioScuola[68882:4806378] 20150601
(lldb) print dayOneInCurrentMonth
(__NSDate *) $1 = 0x79e579c0 2015-05-31 21:00:00 UTC`. As you see here is 2015/06/08, which means that the 1st date must be 2015/06/01, but the date was 2015/05/31.

Comment: The point is, you should **not** use `NSLog()` or `po dayOneInCurrentMonth` to display the date as that uses `[NSDate description]` which will print the date in UTC which is fundamentally what's confusing you.  This issue has been discussed many times on this site.

Comment: Ok, @Droppy : `(lldb) po dayOneInCurrentMonth
2015-05-31 21:00:00 +0000`.  May be the conversion between NSDate to output is really my problem. I will check, 10x. Obviously `po` is working the same way as `print` in this case.

Comment: @new2ios just NSLog may be you get proper answer.I try while code in my machine.

Comment: No (to reiterate) do **not** use `NSLog()`.

Comment: Why only `Gregorian` calendar? Why not to use the current calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Create `NSDateComponents` from `[NSDate date]`, set the current day to 1 and re-create your `NSDate` object:

```
- (NSDate *) dateAtStartOfMonth
{
    //Not tested!!!
    NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [comp setDay:1];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comp];
}
```